# CodeIgniter "No input file specified"

Tags: codeigniter

I just finished developing a website using codeigniter and in the end the person I was developing for switched from one hosting service to another. Now, when I try to go in the website at first I got a message saying

> "No input file specified"

after going through some websites I found out I could try and fix this by using index.php? changing these on the config.php file:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php?";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "QUERY_STRING";
```

I tried that but now I am getting this message:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property:
>   Login::$session
>
> Filename: controllers/login.php
>
> Line Number: 121
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   userdata() on a non-object in
>   /home/content/34/5024634/html/pdv/application/controllers/login.php
>   on line 121

on line 121 of controllers/login.php you see this:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE)
```

which works perfectly fine on the old server as well as on localhost. Now, going back to the previous host isn't an option according to my client so I've been stuck with this error for a while now and haven't been able to find any solution, would any of you guys know how to fix this?

The most helpful websites I've checked out are these two:
http://anon83.wordpress.com/2007/12/11/codeigniter-vs-godaddy-problems/
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Godaddy_Installaton_Tips/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably forgot to load your session library

`$this->load->library('session');` in your construct or autoload it.

Comment: spent so much time trying to figure out the other problem I can't believe I overlooked this...I feel so stupid...thanks haha